# Better way to divide a file which has marks for separate positions in Python

Tags: python

I have a following kind of file:

```
--- part0 ---
some
strings
--- part1 ---
some other
strings
--- part2 ---
...
```

I'd like to get any part of the file as a python list:

```
x = get_part_of_file(part=0)
print x # => should print ['some', 'strings']
x = get_part_of_file(part=1)
print x # => should print ['some other', 'strings']
```

So, **my question** is what is the simplest way to implement `get_part_of_file` method used above.

My (ugly) solution is like below:

```
def get_part_of_file(part, separate_str="part"):
    def does_match_to_separate(line):
        return re.compile("{}.*{}".format(separate_str, part)).match(line)
    def get_first_line_num_appearing_separate_str(lines):
        return len(list(end_of_loop() if does_match_to_separate(line, part) else line for line in lines))

    with open("my_file.txt") as f:
      lines = f.readlines()

    # get first line number of the required part
    first_line_num = get_first_line_num_appearing_separate_str(part)
    # get last line number of the required part
    last_line_num = get_first_line_num_appearing_separate_str(part + 1) - 1  
    return lines[first_line_num:last_line_num]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expression to parse the string. Look at this example here and try it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uI0qL3/1):

```
--- part(?P<part_number>\d+) ---\s(?P<part_value>[\w\s]*)
```

This parses the given string into following groups:

- MATCH 1
  part_number [8-9]   `0`
  part_value  [14-27] `some
  strings`
- MATCH 2
  part_number [35-36] `1`
  part_value  [41-60] `some other
  strings`

Now in python you cant get all groups with

```
import re
parts = re.finditer(your_regex_pattern, text)

for p in parts:
   print("Part %s: %s" % (p.group('part_number'), p.group('part_value'))
   # or return the element with the part-number you want.
```

The only problem you can run into is, that at the moment the regex pattern does only cover Chars, Spaces and Newlines `\w\s`. If there are other characters in the value of your parts, you have to extend this pattern to match more chars.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) you can write something like

```
>>> input_file = open('input', 'r')
>>> content = input_file.read()
>>> content_parts = re.split('.+?part\d+.+?\n', content)

>>> content_parts
['', 'some\nstrings\n', 'some other\nstrings\n', '']

>>> [ part.split('\n') for part in content_parts if part ]
[['some', 'strings', ''], ['some other', 'strings', '']]
```